# How can i change the position of pagination or search box in jquery bootgrid?

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

I have tried to change the position of jquery bootgrid pagination and serach box but cant get proper way to solve the issue.How can i change the position of these?

Comment: you can get the id of search box and pagination id and move the position using script or css

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Templates should do the trick.

```
$("#grid-basic").bootgrid({
            templates: {
                footer: "<div id=\"{{ctx.id}}\" class=\"{{css.footer}}\"><div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-sm-3\"><p class=\"{{css.pagination}}\"></p></div><div class=\"col-sm-9 infoBar\"><div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-sm-3\" style=\"float:left;\"><p class=\"{{css.search}}\"></p></div><div class=\"col-sm-3\" style=\"float:left;\"><p class=\"{{css.infos}}\"></p></div><div class=\"col-sm-3\" style=\"float:right;\"><p class=\"{{css.actions}}\"></p></div></div></div></div></div>",
                header: ""
            }
        });
```